# Wordpress - Insert lines in between wordpress generated lines in .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to dynamically add a few lines in between the lines wordpress generates in the .htaccess file.

This is how the .htaccess file looks when wordpress is generating it:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I want to add my lines in between 
RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]

and

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# BEGIN THIS DL-FILE.PHP ADDITION
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*content/uploads/PROTECTEDFOLDER/.*
RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/(PROTECTEDFOLDER/.*)$ wordpress/dl-file.php?file=$1 [QSA,L]
# END THIS DL-FILE.PHP ADDITION

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I have tried to use the [mod_rewrite_rules filter](http://codex.wordpress.org/User:Amereservant/Editing_and_Customizing_htaccess_Indirectly#Adding_your_own_.htaccess_contents_via_WordPress) to add the lines, but only managed to add lines above and under the wordpress generated lines.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use the Generate Rewrite Rules action to open the `.htaccess` file and insert your extra bit?

http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/generate_rewrite_rules

This is some pseudo code:

```
// On the generate_rewrite_rules hook...

// Grab the htaccess file
$htaccess = file_get_contents(get_home_path() . '.htaccess');
// find where you want to insert
$character_position = strpos($htaccess, "RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f"); 
$new_htaccess = substr_replace($htaccess, "#BEGIN ...", $character_position, 0);
// Save the file... etc
```

It may be a bit mucky, but to my mind works better than getting involved in the actual built in rewrite functions.

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply. I tested your suggestion now. It looks like generate_rewrite_rules dosent run when i referesh my permalinks.. And substr_replace is creating duplicates when im running the function with admin_init action hook (just for testing).